# The type of column <column_name> conflicts with the type of other columns specified in the UNPIVOT list

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
@query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT TOP 7 CAST(',' + QUOTENAME(c.name) AS NVARCHAR(50)) 
                from tempdb.sys.columns c where object_id =
                object_id('tempdb..#MyTempTable')
                AND c.name NOT IN ('description')
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
    ,1,1,'')

SET @query = 'SELECT * FROM #MyTempTable              
          UNPIVOT (
            Qty FOR Customer_Name IN (' + @cols + ')
          ) unpvt 
          WHERE [description] NOT IN (''Grand Total'') ORDER BY [Customer_Name] ASC'

exec sp_executesql @query;
```

Above is my code, I don't know which part causes error, but if I only select Top 6 and below, it is fine.

For My temporary Table

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#MyTempTable') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #MyTempTable
SELECT * INTO #MyTempTable FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
'Excel 12.0;Database=E:\Book2.xlsx', 'SELECT * FROM [March$A2:ZZ]')
```

For Success:
[imagehere](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zW14U.png)

For Error:
[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2qmv2.png)

Comment: Add the structure of #MyTempTable and the print of @query before executing when it fails and when it runs with the top.

Comment: Add information about error

Comment: It sounds like one or more of the column you are unpivoting doesn't have the same data type or collation as the other columns? You need to make sure all the columns that you are unpivoting have the same type.

Comment: I've tried to use the manual import of data and I found out that some of the columns are float and some are nvarchar. I changed the filetype to csv and try to manual import of data, then I checked all the data type. All Fields now have the same data type.
Thank You.